# local variable guid is replaced by new GUID Value while reading a json file from URL

Tags: url, c#-4.0, json.net, json

I am very new to json

Am having a json file in URL which is,

[image]

and am getting all the data into a list as below

```
        System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
        string json = wc.DownloadString("http://192.168.1.7:90/eawebportal/poc/elements/index");
        List<JsonFormat> myDeserializedObjList = (List<JsonFormat>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(List<JsonFormat>));
```

and am getting the list in **myDeserializedObjList** .Where JsonFormat is a class as below

```
    public class JsonFormat
    {
        public string guid;
        public string type;
        public string name;

    }
```

My expected OUTPUT is:

guid= 1-1-1-1-1-1-1  **,** type= Requirement  **,** name = element name
guid= 2-2-2-2-2-2-2  **,** type= Requirement  **,** name = element name

but it give output as

guid= 539fe407-b5c8-4e02-ba7a-1410c0a80107  **,** type= Requirement **,**   name = element name
guid= 539fe407-c0b8-4301-bf22-1410c0a80107  **,** type= Requirement **,**  name = element name

Why its comin so..??

Comment: You must have actual GUIDs in your data, contrary to what you show above in your example JSON above.  That is what a GUID looks like.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier

Comment: @BrianRogers Thanks and even i know about GUID  ,but here am simply declaring a variable in name of "guid" and am hard coding the value to it.

Answer (score 1):

If I use completely hardcoded data in a console application, it works as expected (see below).  So, either the downloaded data file is different than you're showing, or else you have something else in your code that is changing it.

```
class Program
{
    {
        string json = @"
        [
            { ""guid"" : ""1-1-1-1-1-1-1"", ""type"" : ""Requirement"", ""name"" : ""element name"" },
            { ""guid"" : ""2-2-2-2-2-2-2"", ""type"" : ""Requirement"", ""name"" : ""element name"" },
            { ""guid"" : ""3-3-3-3-3-3-3"", ""type"" : ""Requirement"", ""name"" : ""element name"" },
            { ""guid"" : ""4-4-4-4-4-4-4"", ""type"" : ""Requirement"", ""name"" : ""element name"" }
        ]";

        List<JsonFormat> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonFormat>>(json);

        foreach (JsonFormat jf in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("guid: " + jf.guid);
            Console.WriteLine("type: " + jf.type);
            Console.WriteLine("name: " + jf.name);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    public class JsonFormat
    {
        public string guid;
        public string type;
        public string name;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
guid: 1-1-1-1-1-1-1
type: Requirement
name: element name

guid: 2-2-2-2-2-2-2
type: Requirement
name: element name

guid: 3-3-3-3-3-3-3
type: Requirement
name: element name

guid: 4-4-4-4-4-4-4
type: Requirement
name: element name
```